# Что значит <data> в xml

Tags: android, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какую функцию выполнят `<data>` и `<variable>`?
В гугле ничего не нашел.

Comment: Какую функцию выполнят <data> и <variable>? В гугле ничего не нашел(

Comment: при использовании Databinding в этом блоке создаются переменные для того чтобы прописывать логику напрямую в xml.

Answer (score 1):

Блок `<data>` в `xml` характерен для `databinding`'а.

Подробно можете ознакомиться тут:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

Answer (score 0):

Это теги для работы с DataBinding Android.

Внутри тега  вы задаете переменные  для работы в вашей View.

Например если вы хотите чтоб ваши View обновлялись с помощью ViewModel вы можете написать что-то вроде такого:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.myapp.data.ViewModel" />
    </data>
    <ConstraintLayout... 
  
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewmodel.text}" />
    /> <!-- UI layout's root element -->
</layout>
```

Более подробно можно почитать в [документации](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding). Вот [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/551-urok-18-data-binding-osnovy.html) есть неплохая серия уроков